# Return struct in a Function , Compile error

Tags: c, function, struct

I am practicing on my C programming language skills and when i wrote this code compiler shows a bunch of error but i did not saw what is wrong with this. I am learnt this code on internet so hopefully you can help me :)

here is the code;

```
struct rect {

    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
};



struct rect intersection(struct rect m, struct rect n) {
    struct rect intersection;
    if((n.x1 > m.x1) && (n.x1 < m.x2) && (n.y1 > m.y1 ) && (n.y1 < m.y2)){
                    rect intersection = {.x1=n.x1, .y1=n.y2, .x2=m.x2, .y2=m.y2};
                    return intersection;
                    }
    else if((m.x1 > n.x1) && (m.x1 < n.x2) && (m.y1 > n.y1 ) && (m.y1 < n.y2)){
                    rect intersection = {.x1=m.x1, .y1=m.y2, .x2=n.x2, .y2=n.y2};
                    return intersection;
                    }
    return NULL;
}
```

compile errors are at 
    rect intersection = {.x1=m.x1, .y1=m.y2, .x2=n.x2, .y2=n.y2};
    *error: field name not in record or union initializer

```
*error: incompatible types when returning type ‘int’ but ‘struct rect’ was expected
                     return intersection;
                     ^
*error: incompatible types when returning type ‘void *’ but ‘struct rect’ was expected
return NULL;
^
```

IF I MISS SOME INFO , PLEASE TELL ME

THANK YOU :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be "struct rect intersection = {"? (missing "struct")

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you've used the same name for the local struct and also the function?

Comment: i tried add struct @immibis , it gives a less error so thats true , thank you :) but still there is something wrong with returning NULL :(

Comment: Because you said your function returned a rect and NULL is not a rect.

Comment: i thought NULL is returning for all types , am i wrong?

Comment: No, pointers mainly (or any integer/number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 struct rect intersection = {.x1=n.x1, .y1=n.y2, .x2=m.x2, .y2=m.y2};//like this

 return NULL;//return intersection
```

My proposal is using pointer:the function return `struct rect *`,if this,you can return `NULL` when there is some error.

Comment: But then you need a non-local `struct rect` to return a pointer to.

Answer (score 5):

The return type of your function is `struct rect`. NULL is a pointer or 0. You should either return a `struct rect` or change the return type of your function to `struct rect*` and a pointer to a heap `malloc`'d `struct rect` instead.

Comment: That's one of the two problems; the other is the missing keyword `struct`. In C++, you don't need to repeat `struct`, but this is C.

Answer (score 1):

user2151287 suggested returning a pointer; but then you need something to point to, because

```
// this code is wrong
struct rect *some_function()
{
    struct rect x = {stuff};
    return &x;
}
```

is undefined behaviour - it has a chance of working anyway depending on how you use it, but eventually it won't work, and you'll be very confused.

You could return an empty rectangle (width and height = 0) instead:

```
struct rect x = {.x1=0, .y1=0, .x2=0, .y2=0};
return x;
```

By the way, your `intersection` function returns the wrong result in this case:

[image]

Comment: i saw this wrong results , yes , thanks for detailed information. i am looking for a solution for this and i am trying to fix. I will try to set one corner to (0,0) and increase to other all corners with which value that i use to set the corner to (0,0). And after that, all rectangles will move to same direction and same distance. after i find a intersection, i will set intersection corners to old position by previous change's opposite. What are you thinking about this?